# Creating a Swinging in Unity without rigidBody

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, rope

**Alright so im working with swinging effect in unity FPS character controller where i need to add a swinging part . Im trying to have a swing smooth direction based on the hit point using raycasting and transform.position . For My heirarchy i have a Player who has a Main Camera as child and i have gun whose a child of main camera and a parent of a guntip where the rope will struck off from . Im trying to rotate using Cross product of the hit point and the player transform position but i cant get it right and i cant find any other way to do it as well .**

````
    void start Swinging()
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime * 12f ;
        Vector3 swingDirection = Vector3.Cross(transform.localPosition, (hook.transform.position - transform.position).normalized).normalized;
        float speed = Mathf.PingPong(timer, 180);
        velocity.y = 0;
       
        transform.Translate(swingDirection * speed * Time.deltaTime);

       


    }


    void createHook()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = new Ray(camerapos.position, camerapos.forward);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100f, hookMask))
        {
            hook = Instantiate(hookprefab, hit.point, Quaternion.identity);
            hookNormal = hit.normal;
            canSwing = true;
        }
    }```

**Here's the code I am working currently on where I am calling them when the mouse is clicked once for the Create Hook and when the mouse is held down the swinging function** 
Would be glad if you all can share your thoughts on how to do it right way I'm a beginner in unity currently learning.
````

Comment: Have you tried using hinge joints?

Comment: @MidnightDemise Maybe this will help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HPjuTK91MA8

Comment: i dont have a rigidBody i have a characterController...

Comment: Turning off the character controller while swinging and turning a rigidbody on for the duration of the swing is not a bad solution. This problem is really best solved by unity's physics engine... attempting to roll this yourself would be a bit of a pain